# Different variable scoping using "let" keyword between browsers

Tags: javascript, function, loops, scope

The below piece of code, returns different behaviuours if you execute it in `Chrome` and `Firefox`.

```js
var obj = {
  key: 'val',
  key2: 'val'
};

function x(b) {
  setTimeout(b, 1000);
}

var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (let ki of keys) {
  x(function() {
    console.log(ki); // Prints key2 key2 in Firefox, key key2 in Chrome
  });
}
```

Why is happening this ? It's a bug ? Should be the right output the one returned by Chrome taking in count the specs ?

Comment: Firefox's implementation isn't yet complete. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-let In the meantime, create a local `let` variable inside the loop and use that. `let kki = ki;`

Comment: It looks like an incomplete implementation in Firefox.  There is supposed to be a completely unique variable `ki` for each iteration of the loop and Firefox is not yet doing that.  It is sharing the same variable for all iterations.

Comment: Thank you both! =)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that there is a scope created for that `let`, but the scope basically wraps the entire `for-of` statement. So it's like `{let ki; for (ki of keys) {...} }` Firefox had `let` before it was spec'd, and the spec didn't end up matching their implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's a bug. You can try running it on jsBin with Babel enabled, and you see the Chrome behavior in FireFox:

http://jsbin.com/nadikatari/edit?html,js,console,output

Sounds like FireFox hasn't implemented let yet. You really should be transpiling to ES5 using Babel, if you want to use ES6 at this point.

Comment: Thank for your input and the jsBin!! I'll accept your answer in 6 mins.